# Swift getElementById of HTML String

Tags: javascript, html, swift, web, getelementbyid

small question:
I have an HTML String from which I need the href content of a specific element.

I know there is WKWebView.evaluateJavaScript() but I then would have to first create a WebView wouldn't I? Which seems too much effort for what I want to do..

I also could manually search the String for "id='xyz'" and get the element and the stuff from there but that seems pretty ugly and also not as simple as I thought..

Do you have any ideas? ^^